# Is Complete Statistic Uncorrelated with Ancillary Statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, ancillary-statistics, complete-statistics

By Basu's theorem, we know that any ancillary statistic is independent of a statistic that is both sufficient and complete. I was wondering if the assumption of sufficiency and completeness can be relaxed.

If $T$ is a complete statistic for a family of distributions $\mathcal P = \{ P_{\theta} , \theta \in \Theta \}$,  then for any ancillary statistic $S$, can we show that $S $ and $T$ are uncorrelated?

Comment: To be uncorrelated would mean that S and T would be independent

Comment: @Jon No, lack of correlation does not imply independence.

Comment: @dsaxton, that is correct. I take that comment back.

Comment: What do you mean? Complete but not sufficient? Do such a beast exist?

Comment: On the other hand if two statistics are independent then they are uncorrelated. So what are you looking for in the question?